# New budgeting Program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below is a program I'm writing to help myself budget.

I am still new to programming and was wondering what you all thought about the code, or what I could improve at and what is good.

This works by gathering data and information from the income and bills to help show you your budget. My end goal with this is to have a good visual program that could show you your finances better.

```
def mainmenu():
    print("Welcome to the main menu.\n"
          "below is a list of options for you to choose from.\n"
          "In the help menu you, can see the proper steps and instructions to follow.\n\n"''
          "Enter 'menu' for the main menu\n"
          "Enter 'help' for the help menu\n"
          "Enter 'income' to find your income\n"
          "Enter 'bills' to enter bills\n"
          "Enter 'budget to find the budget for your salary\n"
          "Enter 'quit' to  quit the program")


print("!!THIS IS A ROUGH ESTIMATE, TAXES ARE NOT ACCOUNTED FOR")
#bring up menu asking to choose sections bring up income expenses and budgeting find a way to clear screen when new menu is brought up

mainmenu()
#switch to new algorithim
def BasicIncome(Weekly_income):
    print("|weekly_income    monthly income    monthly hours worked    bimonthly_pay    quarterly salary    yearly_salary\n"
          "|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
          "|" +
          str(Weekly_income)+"            " + str(monthly_income)+"            " + str(monthly_hours_worked)+"                   " + str(bimonthly_pay)+"           " + str(quarterly_salary)+"             " + str(yearly_salary)+
          "\n\n")
    return Weekly_income, monthly_income, monthly_hours_worked, bimonthly_pay, quarterly_salary, yearly_salary


#Enter basic bill summary
#this is all a basic idea and can be broken down in a different section. This is just a brief income summary

print("\n\nNow that we have a brief summary of your income we will look over your expenses")

#compare bills to budget and income
def bills(monthly_income, expense_one, total_monthly_expense, bimonthly_expenses, quarterly_expenses, yearly_expenses):
    print("Your bi-monthly expense cost is ${}".format(bimonthly_expenses))
    print("Your quartley expense cost is ${}".format(quarterly_expenses))
    print("Your yearly expense cost is ${}".format(yearly_expenses))
    return (monthly_income, expense_one, total_monthly_expense)


def budget(FPR, TPR, TIPS):
    print("50% of your monthly budget is ${}".format(FPR))
    print("30% of your monthly budget is ${}".format(TPR))
    print("20% of your monthly budget is ${}\n\n\n\n".format(TIPS))
    print("After your bills your monthly expense budget is ${}".format(float(FPR - expense_one)))
    print("Your weekly spending budget is ${}".format(float(TIPS / 4)))
    print("After two months of saving you will have saved ${}".format(float(TPR * 2)))
    print("Every week you will save ${}" .format(float(TPR / 4)))


def expenses(expense_one, totaly_monthly_expenses, monthly_income, bimonthly_expenses, quarterly_expenses, yearly_expenses):
    print(
        "|income after expenses/ bi-monthly     quarterly     yearly\n"
        "|----------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
        "|\n" +
        "|                      " +
        "" + "-" + str(bimonthly_expenses) + "         " + "-" + str(
            quarterly_expenses) + "        " + "-" + str(yearly_expenses) +
        "\n\n")
    return expense_one, totaly_monthly_expenses, monthly_income, expense_one, bimonthly_expenses, quarterly_expenses, yearly_expenses


while True:
    UserInput = input("{}Enter a command:\n> " .format("\n\n"))
    if UserInput.upper() == "HELP":
        #make help menu
        pass
    elif UserInput.upper() == "MENU":
        mainmenu()
    elif UserInput.upper() == "INCOME":
        Weekly_income = float(input("Enter your weekly income:\n> "))

        monthly_income = float(Weekly_income * 4)
        bimonthly_pay = float(Weekly_income * 8)
        monthly_hours_worked = float(40 * 4)
        quarterly_salary = float(Weekly_income * 16)
        yearly_salary = float(Weekly_income * 52)
        BasicIncome(Weekly_income)
# need call to function
    elif UserInput.upper() == "BILLS":
        expense_one = float(input("Enter the amount of the bill you have in total\n>$"))
        total_monthly_expense = float(monthly_income - expense_one)
        bimonthly_expenses = float(expense_one * 2)
        quarterly_expenses = float(expense_one * 4)
        yearly_expenses = float(expense_one * 12)

        bills(monthly_income, expense_one, total_monthly_expense, bimonthly_expenses, quarterly_expenses,yearly_expenses)

    elif UserInput.upper() == "BUDGET":
        FPR = float(monthly_income / 2)
        TPR = float(monthly_income / 3.33)
        TIPS = float(monthly_income / 5)

        budget(FPR, TPR, TIPS)

    else:
        UserInput.upper() == "QUIT"
        quit()
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python so I'll stick to a +1 for clean code. Some positives that I noticed are: concise but descriptive variable names, broken out `print` statements instead of new lining to death on a single line, and of course, comments.

Answer (score 1):

OK so a few points to neaten things up:

- Multiline strings are available in Python like so:

```
s = """
Line 1
Line 2
"""
```

Use these where possible to avoid all the `'\n'` characters and needless speech marks when printing multiline blocks.

- Generally speaking, lay out your code with all function definitions at the top and the body of the program below. Currently, you have one `print` statement and a call to `mainmenu()` in the middle of the functions getting lost.
- `BasicIncome` shouldn't really be using `monthly_income`, `monthly_hours` etc. from the global scope. (Off the top of my head I'm not even sure if it will work like that!) Pass them as arguments to the function if you really need them.
- Your function names could be more informative. Take `bills` and `budget` for example: a good way to name them put the name into a sentence "The role of this function is to {{function_name}}". `printBills` and `printBudget` would probably be more appropriate here.
- In `bills` and `expenses`, there is no need to return all of the arguments to the functions at the end. You haven't modified them in any way therefore anything that called the function will actually already have access to them!
- Try and stick to strict naming conventions. You have mixed PascalCase (e.g. `UserInput`) and snake_case (e.g. expense_one) variables.
- You might want to do some input validation. Consider what would happen if somebody enters "none" as their income.
- I think at the bottom of your program, you might want `elif UserInput.upper() == "QUIT":`. Currently a typo will quit your program

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to read which is a good point. It is much easier to debug code that you can read easily. You can avoid having to break each line by using 3 single quotes at the start and end of the text.

```
def mainmenu():
    print('''
    Welcome to the main menu.
    below is a list of options for you to choose from.
    In the help menu you, can see the proper steps and instructions to follow.
    Enter 'menu' for the main menu
    Enter 'help' for the help menu
    Enter 'income' to find your income
    Enter 'bills' to enter bills
    Enter 'budget to find the budget for your salary
    Enter 'quit' to  quit the program
    ''')
```

I would consider using classes to capture information because they are very easy to work with.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, money_in, money_out):
    self.name = name
    self.money_in = money_in
    self.money_out = money_out

  def __str__(self):
        return '''
    | Money in | Money out |  Name    |

        {}         {}        {}

    '''.format(self.money_in, self.money_out, self.name)

user = Person('Johnny', 1200, 800)
print(user)
```

When this is returned you get:

```
| Money in | Money out |  Name   |                                                 

    1200        800       Johnny
```

In your while loop you are calculating the users input. You can use functions to handle that:

```
def main():
  option = input('enter name:> ')
  user.name = option
  print('\t\t, ', user)

while True:
  choice = input(':> ')
  if choice.lower() == 'main':     # .lower() converts any input into lowercase
    main()


etc...
```